# CString construction from std::string - copy chars or pointer

Tags: c++, mfc, cstring, stdstring

If I convert a `std::string` into a `CString` using something like:

```
std::string ss("Foo");
CString cs( ss.c_str() );
```

Does the `CString` copy the characters from `ss` or does it simply copy the `char*` pointer?

My understanding of the `c_str()` function is that it returns a pointer to a character array owned by the `std::string`. So having a `CString` using this internally would seem like a really bad idea as any nonconstant method on either of them would then invalidate the pointer held in the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CString` constructor that takes a `const char*` will copy the data into its internal structure.  It's the same as doing this:

`CString test = "This is a test"`
or even this
`CString test("This is a test")`

Answer (score 1):

Documentation of CString constructor [(link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cws1zdt8.aspx) says:

> The constructors copy the input data into new allocated storage.

So, your data must be copied.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314317%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) says that the string will be copied, so it will not manipulate the std::string buffer directly.

> CString( LPCSTR lpsz );
>
> lpsz - A null-terminated string to be copied into this CString object.